# How to test JPA adaptor steps in Spring Integration Flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an integration flow (simplified version below) which has multiple steps with JPA adapter. With the first one, i'm getting the existing record from database with the id, and in the second one, saving the updated entity into the db.

```
@Autowired private EntityManager entityManager;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
  return IntegrationFlows
      .from(
          Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory(), “inTopic”)
              .id("InboundKafkaAdapter"))
      .transform(transform())
      .filter(filter())
      .handle(
          Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManager)
              .idExpression("headers['" + Headers.ID + "']")
              .entityClass(TestEntity.class),
          s -> s.advice(interceptForResult()).requiresReply(true))
      .filter(secondFilter())
      .transform(transformUpdatedEntity())
      .handle(jpaAdapter(), ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)
      .handle(
          Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate())
                  .topic(“outTopic”))
      .get();
}

private JpaUpdatingOutboundEndpointSpec jpaAdapter() {
  return Jpa.updatingGateway(this.entityManager)
      .entityClass(TestEntity.class)
      .flush(true)
      .persistMode(PersistMode.MERGE);
}
```

For testing, I would like to mock all the external parties and test the flow itself. I've used IntegrationFlowContext as below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringIntegrationTest
public class SampleFlowTest {
 
 
  @Mock
  private SampleFlow sampleFlow;

  @Test
  public void testSampleFlow() throws IOException {
  
    IntegrationFlow originalFlow = sampleFlow.flow();
    IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
      integrationFlowContext.registration(originalFlow).register();

     final Message<?> request =
      MessageBuilder.withPayload(“somePayload)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, “inTopic”)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "1")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, "1")
        .build();

    Message<?> response =
      flowRegistration.getMessagingTemplate().sendAndReceive(request);


    flowRegistration.destroy();
  }

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public static class Config {
// Some beans for config
}
}
```

When i run the test, the flow continues until the first JPA step. Since the logic in interceptForResult() was not working, it was creating an issue. I removed the first one to see the behaviour for the second, and it also throws an exception for transactionManager bean been missing.

I also tried to use `substituteMessageHandlerFor` for mocking these 2 handlers (with setting ids), but again getting a missing bean exception for the ids i defined. I think, it is because that the original flow class is mocked.

So, could you please help to mock JPA steps in my test? Thanks!

**UPDATED** -- Test implementation

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringIntegrationTest (noAutoStartup = {"InboundKafkaAdapter"})
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
  classes = Application.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
public class FlowTest {

  @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

  @Autowired private MyIntegrationFlow integrationFlow;

  @Autowired private QueueChannel testChannel;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(“flow.channel#0")
  private MessageChannel flow;

  @Test
  public void test() {

    Message request = generateMessageForEvent();

    MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mockMessageHandler().handleNextAndReply(Function.identity());

    this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor(
      "JpaRetrievingGateway", mockMessageHandler);
    this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor(
      "JpaUpdatingGateway", mockMessageHandler);
    this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor(
      "OutboundKafkaAdapter", mockMessageHandler);

    flow.send(request);

    Message<String> reply = (Message<String>) testChannel.receive(0);
    Assert.assertNotNull("reply should not be null", reply);
}


@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public static class Config {

  @Bean
  public QueueChannel testChannel(){
    return new QueueChannel();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `IntegrationFlow` starts with a `MessageChannel`, even if it has that `from(Kafka.`, there is still an `inputChannel`. In your production code an initiator of the flow is going to be a `ConsumerRecord` from Apache Kafka, but for testing it is fully OK to send a message directly to the first channel of the flow.

So, step one: no need in any extra dynamic flow registration trying to mock and patch everything whatever you have in a main flow. You just need:

```
@Autowired
IntegrationFlow flow;

...

flow.getInputChannel()
```

Since you are not interested in Kafka at all, you really can just use `substituteMessageHandlerFor()` for that last `.handle(Kafka.)`.

And since you are interested in the `Jpa.updatingGateway()` you can mock that handler with replying `MockMessageHandler`.

In the main flow you do:

```
.handle(
      Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate())
              .topic(“outTopic”)
              .id("kafkaOutboundEndpoint"))
```

In the test you do:

```
 MessageHandler mockMessageHandler =
            mockMessageHandler()
                    .handleNextAndReply(Function.identity());

    this.mockIntegrationContext
            .substituteMessageHandlerFor("kafkaOutboundEndpoint",
                    mockMessageHandler);
```

And request-reply interaction:

```
MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
Message<?> reply = template.sendAndReceive(flow.getInputChannel(), testMessage);
```

Or you can just interact with that `mockMessageHandler` using `handleNext()` callback for assertions. Then you don't need a reqeust-reply and you ca just send to the `flow.getInputChannel()`.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me to the right direction.
I've tried to send the request with `template.sendAndReceive` for the kafka inputAdapter but got a "MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'." exception, even if i tried different approaches, such as adding`@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = {"InboundKafkaAdapter"})`. Btw, i also see inputChannel of the flow as null.

Comment: What Spring Integration version do you use? I'll play with that tomorrow or after weekend anyway.

Comment: It is 5.5.16. I just tried to upgrade to 6.0.3, but there are some build issues that i need to check first. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: I had to add the first channel with autowired, then i was able to trigger the flow with calling send method on it:
` @Autowired
  @Qualifier("flow.channel#0")
  private MessageChannel fromEvent;`
It also complained about missing reply channel, so i also introduced a queuechannel for it and set it in the message header.
Now, i am getting an error in the `Jpa.retrievingGateway` step, it's complaining about missing db table. So, looks like i have a problem with its mocking as it is still trying to access db.

Comment: Well, I thought your question was really about testing a result of the `.handle(jpaAdapter(), ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)`. So, it is expected for the test environment that DB is ready for interaction. If you are not interested in that, then you also need to mock this handler step as well.

Comment: This is my handler:
 `.handle(
            Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManager)
                .idExpression("headers['" + RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY + "']")
                .entityClass(TestEntity.class),
            s -> s.advice(interceptResult()).requiresReply(true).id("JpaRetrievingGateway"))` 

And this is the mock which seems not to be working: 
`MessageHandler mockHandler =
      mockMessageHandler()
        .handleNextAndReply(Function.identity());

    this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor(
      "JpaRetrievingGateway", mockHandler, false);
`

Comment: Why not `autoStartup`?

Comment: I actually tried both, but still not worked.

Comment: What error do you get in that case? Do you also mock your `.handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(` endpoint?

Comment: Yes, i also mocked it. I can see that the flow continues until JPA retrieval step, here getting this error: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "REQUEST" not found;`

Comment: OK. It probably would be great if you share your current test code to analyze.

Comment: The above error is for when autoStartup is false.
When autoStartup is true, then there is no exception, but flow just does not continue after this retrieval step (including this step), just skips the rest and returns a response to my replychannel immediately.

Comment: I see the problem: you need to have individual `mockMessageHandler()` for each substitution. Right now you are reuse the same instance and it ends up with the state from the last one only.

Comment: Ohh, thank you! With different handlers, it worked like a charm!